# Generate Calendar Text File in Linux

Tags: calendar

how to generate a text file in Linux as below.

Workweek, with 7 dates on each line.

```
2016WW22=20160521:20160522:20160523:20160524:20160525:20160526:20160527:
2016WW23=20160528:20160529:20160530:20160531:20160601:20160602:20160603:
```

Comment: Would `cal -w -y` be enough?  From that you can grep and awk what you need.

Comment: what i meant is i wanted to generate the file looks as above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
for i in {0..202} ; do date --date "$i days 2016-05-21" +%Y%m%d ; done |\
   awk 'NR%7==1 {print ""} {printf $1 ":"}' | \
   awk 'BEGIN { n=22 } $1!="" { printf "2016WW%02d=%s\n",n++,$1}'
```

Adjust numbers to your likings.